# Importing Excel file to ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, import, excel, ms-access

https://www.dropbox.com/s/disaisc1wrv1mbi/Form470_2015-02-11-13-10-13.xls?dl=0

I downloaded that from the USAC (people that manage USF, E-Rate, etc.) web site. I've tried many combinations of importing to Access, linking ArcCatalog to Access, ensuring headers don't start with a number, changing spaces to underscores in headers, etc. I always end up with:

Start Time: Wed Feb 11 12:32:14 2015
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (TableToTable).
Failed at Wed Feb 11 12:32:14 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)

I read a few posts on different sites about the issue, but it was always with people using their own Python scripts. I'm just using the standard ArcCatalog import function.

Ideas?

Comment: Did you remove the question marks, plus signs, and slashes in the field names?

Comment: Can you add the first few lines of the table to your question?

Comment: @DanC there are 73 columns in the spreadsheet, so that might not be terribly feasible. First thing I note, all **/ + ?** need to be removed from column headings. Some may need to be shortened as well - see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000000t000000 Second, you may need to first save to CSV and then [create a schema.ini](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000010000000) file for the data types to be properly read. Since the file has a number of blank cells and Arc only looks at the first so many when determining data types.

Comment: Also, the data in the table is pretty 'dirty'. Dates may not read in right, you must ensure any columns whose values are mixed numeric and string are read as strings (and that includes any non-numeric characters, like dashes or / in numbers). Only columns that contain *only* numbers can be read in as a numeric (and length will determine if int, double, or float need to be used). Note zips shouldn't be stored as numbers, but as strings. Else your leading/trailing 0's are going to disappear. Also note rules are different for shapefiles vs geodatabases, and that includes just tables with no geom.

Answer (score 1):

You may be having some issues related to the characters contained in the table. Try to get rid of anything that is neither alphanumeric or underscore. Not sure if you came to this point but this is my guess. Arc does only allow letters, numbers, and underscores.

Here are some tips regarding this:
http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/23087

Best,
Ricardo O.

Comment: *bangs firsts on desk* I can't believe that a program that costs as much as ArcMap does doesn't have basic input sanitation. That's like a CIS101 class (okay, not really that simple, but any coder should be doing that).

I don't have it yet, but I'm working my way through Excel's replace function.

Comment: Arc is ancient in many of it parts, it is basically a Frankenstein, just to give an idea: you can't save rasters if there is any gap on the folder's destination file path.